# Tmux Mouse scroll broken

Tags: terminal, mouse, tmux, scrolling

Ok, so before any one gets it wrong let me clear that I am totally aware how to scroll using the keyboard in tmux.

I have been using the following line `set -ga terminal-overrides ',xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'` to use the mouse wheel for scrolling.

My `tmux.conf`:

```
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display-message "Config reloaded."

source "/usr/share/tmux/powerline.conf"

set -g default-terminal 'screen-256color'
set -ga terminal-overrides ',xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'

set-option -g allow-rename off

bind h split-window -h
bind v split-window -v
unbind '"'
unbind %
```

My `.zshrc`

```
alias tmuxn='tmux new-session -s $$'
_trap_exit() { tmux kill-session -t $$; }
trap _trap_exit EXIT
if [[ "$TERM" == "xterm-256color" ]];then
  tmuxn
fi
if [[ "$TERM" == "screen" ]] || [[ "$TERM" == "screen-256color" ]];then
  if [ -f `which powerline-daemon` ]; then
    powerline-daemon -q
    POWERLINE_ZSH_CONTINUATION=1
    POWERLINE_ZSH_SELECT=1
    . /usr/share/powerline/zsh/powerline.zsh
  fi
fi
```

Lately when I try scrolling, **output is missing a number of lines** and is often incomplete. I have tried a bunch of configuration setup, none of which have worked so far.
Any Advice?